# Unable to use filter uglifyjs in assetic without having a segfault

Tags: symfony, assetic, uglifyjs

It seems that i can't use **`uglifyjs`** filter with assetic on a Symfony2 context, as it seems to cause **segmentation fault**.

```
php app/console assetic:dump 
Dumping all dev assets.
Debug mode is off.

16:35:02 [file+] ...../../web/css/compiled_50f84d1.css
16:35:02 [file+] ...../../web/js/compiled_e371e27.js

Segmentation fault: 11
```

My config looks like :

```
assetic:
    debug:            false
    use_controller:   false
    read_from:        %kernel.root_dir%/../web
    write_to:         %kernel.root_dir%/../web
    bundles: []                                 # disable bundles parsing
    node:             /usr/local/bin/node

    filters:
        cssmin: ~
        uglifyjs: ~
```

And my view :

```
{% javascripts 'js/all.js' 'js/player.js' filter='uglifyjs' output='js/compiled_*.js' %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

As soon as i disable the filter I no longer have the error. I have a fresh install of node and I have `uglify-js@1.3.3 node_modules/uglify-js`

Comment: How do you manage your *AMP stack?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you, but this is how I've setup `uglifyjs` in my `config_prod.yml` to make it work in production only:

```
assetic:
    filters:
        uglifyjs:
            bin: /usr/local/bin/uglifyjs
            no_copyright: true
            apply_to: ["\.coffee$", "\.js$"]
```

Thanks to `apply_to` you don't need to use `filter='uglifyjs'` in the `{% javascripts ... %}` tag.